# What does "with effectiveness for the future" mean?

Tags: meaning

> (...) you shall have the right to withdraw your consent for the data
>   processing, **with effectiveness for the future** (...)
>   (https://productdata.vwgroup.com/data-protection.html)

What does Does it mean that "with effectiveness for the future" mean? Does it mean:

> You have the right to withdraw (...) and this right is effective even
>   in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the withdrawal of the consent applies only to future eventual data sharing, and it does not apply retro-actively.

With other words, as an example, if you withdraw your consent tomorrow, you cannot cancel the data sharing done yesterday.